# Steering Behaviors, Pursuit, How do I predict a linear vector(MATH)?

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

So I working on Steering behaviours, and I have managed to do some simple Seek, Flee, and Arrive S.B. However i am having some isues with the Pursuit S.B.

i have read that in order to calculate a point in the future of my TargetAgent
i should calculate it this way.

```
SVector nVector = v.pos + (vMagnitude * Velocity * time); //This get a point in advance from the agent
```

I Have made a very RAW code from pursuit:

```
SVector CBoid::Pursuit(const SVector& vTarget)
{
//get the vector from this Agent to Target Agent.
SVector nVector = position - vTarget; 

//Acquire the lenght of vector between this and Target.
double vMagnitude = nVector.Magnitude();

//locate the new point and set my current vector to that point.
nVector = vTarget.position + (vTarget.Magnitude() * vTarget.Velocity * vTarget.time);

//if this  Magnitude is less than  target radius, start slowing down. //this part is just an idea.
if (vMagnitude > AGENTS_RADIUS && vMagnitude < 0.01)
{
    double slowDownScalar = vMagnitude / AGENTS_RADIUS;
    nVector * slowDownScalar;
    return Seek(nVector);
}

else
    return Seek(nVector);
```

}

*this is a raw function.

what I dont understand is WHY I need those variables. I have read alot on vectors but not about this prediction method. 
Can anybody explain to me why or how I can predict a future position of my vector? (I mainly want to understand, so i can make my own S.B.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge in Pursuit, as opposed to Arrive, is that you do not know the destination, and it even may change as the target changes its velocity.

An intermediate form is Intercept SB, where you assume that the target has a fixed speed and course. That means you know all future positions, and you can pick one point and plot a course towards it. The exact SB will depend on initial positions, your max acceleration, your max speed, turn rate, and possibly the need to match speed.

With Pursuit, you even need to account for possible changes in target velocity, which means you need to account for the targets max acceleration, speed, and turn rate.

That's why you need all those vectors.

There's no single solution for all cases including yours. You might need to brush up on linear algebra.

Comment: I finally understood how to get a point in future. I always understood the Forumula, but I am always confused becuase i lack a physicall representation.

i got great help in youtube: math for game developer

Comment: Thank you anyways.. I will revisit linear algebra:)